# Tornado packaged in an executable egg - how reference templates

Tags: python, tornado, setuptools

I've created a Tornado web server, which I need to package as an egg (using setuptools)

The project contains a number of html templates and static images, which I've included in my egg as data files. Note the egg is executable, and will not be installed.
I.e.

```
python mytornadoserver.egg
```

The standard way of accessing html templates / static resources is to use the template_path and static_path settings. However within an egg this is not going to work.

I'm trying to play with resource_strings - but no success so far.

I'm stuck at the moment, because I cannot load the html/image files - so I'd be grateful for any help / advice anybody can give

Many thanks,
Marcus

Answer (score 1):

finally resolved the issue:

```
from pkg_resources import resource_filename
template_dir = resource_filename(__name__, "templates")

# then assign the template_dir to your template_path as normal....
```

the resource_files extracts the entire directory to a physical file location, and returns that location.

Comment: It doesn't work for me: resource_filename returns an url like `/usr/local/.../myprogram-egg-info/templates` but the problem is that `myprogram-egg-info` is an egg file instead of a directory. I think I need a way to force egg extraction before calling resource_filename (or, better, install the program in a directory instead of an egg file...)